# Connect AWS S3 to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I'm fairly new to AWS and have a basic setup question. I have an EC2 instance with the standalone version of ElasticSearch installed on it. We are not using the managed services version of ElasticSearch offered by AWS. We have data stored in an S3 bucket. I need to insert data from this S3 bucket into ElasticSearch. From what I've read so far, I need to register my S3 bucket with ElasticSearch in the elasticsearch.yml file. I came across the aws-cloud plugin which may be deprecated now. I went ahead and installed the repository-s3 plugin. Not sure if I would need this plugin for what I'm looking to do.

I tried the following command to register my S3 bucket with ElasticSearch:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/poc-repository' -d'{
    "type": "s3",
    "settings": {
        "bucket": "s3-elasticsearch-poc",
        "region": "us-west-2"        
    }
}'
```

Getting the following error:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"repository_exception","reason":"[poc-repository:{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unknown
>   [repository] type [s3]"}

What is the best way to hook up my S3 bucket with ElasticSearch installed on EC2?

Comment: I'm not using the AWS ElasticService though, this is the standalone version of ES.

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad I must have misread your question. Then you need to make sure to install the [repository-s3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/repository-s3.html) plugin and restart your node.

Comment: Yep, I installed repository-s3 plugin.

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _cat/plugins?v`

Comment: Is this the right command to register the s3 bucket? I'm having some difficulty understanding what exactly this command does.

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/poc-repository' -d'{ "type": "s3", "settings": { "bucket": "s3-elasticsearch-poc", "region": "us-west-2"
} }'


s3-elasticsearch-poc is the name of my s3 bucket.
Will ES create a repository named poc-repository?

I still get the same error mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, but see my previous comment first and can you tell which ES version you're running?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I'm running ES version 5.6.10.

Running sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin list shows I have:
discovery-ec2
repository-s3

I needed to modify the IAM role. I'm able to hook up the s3 bucket now. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out